# Questions with both an interesting tag and an ignored tag are shown strangely in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When I open the top page in Firefox 3.6.12 or Firefox 4.0 Beta 7 on Windows 7, a question with both an interesting tag and an ignored tag is shown in a strange way; it seems that something is wrong with ClearType.

This does not reproduce with IE 8 or Chrome 7.0 on the same system.  Therefore, I suspect that this may be an issue with Firefox rather than an issue with the website.  Despite this, I am posting this issue because (1) I am not completely sure about the cause and (2) even if it is an issue with Firefox, some workaround on the server side might be possible.

Screenshot (click for the original size):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: definitely looks like a glitch, I'm looking into this. (btw, what's the reason to tag a topic as both interesting and ignored?)

Comment: @Jin: Thank you.  I have set the tag [co.combinatorics] as an interesting tag and the tag [big-list] as an ignored tag, and this question happens to have both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Verified.  Thanks!